# SQL queries optimization

Tags: mysql, database, performance, database-performance

I'm having trouble optimizing some sql queries that take in account datetime fields.

First of all, my table structure is the following:

```
  CREATE TABLE info (
  id int NOT NULL auto_increment,
  name varchar(20),
  infoId int,
  shortInfoId int,
  text varchar(255),
  token varchar(60),
  created_at DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
  KEY(created_at));
```

After using explain on some of the simple queries I added the created_at key, that improved most of my simple queries performance. I'm having now trouble with the following query:

```
SELECT min(created_at), max(created_at) from info order by id DESC limit 10000
```

With this query I want to get the timespan between tha last 10k results.

After using explain I get the following results:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE          info    ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL        NULL     4       NULL
```

Any idea on how can I improve the performance of this query?

Comment: Why you Need an `order by`and a `limit`? If i am right you get only one record.

Comment: I'm trying to get the timespan between the last 10k results. Maybe I'm not doing this right.

Comment: You're not doing it right. The usage of functions `MIN()` and `MAX()` assumes an implicit `GROUP BY` that contains the entire table. `LIMIT` is applied after `ORDER BY` which is applied after `GROUP BY`. But `GROUP BY` produces a single row on this query.

Comment: `EXPLAIN` says it wants to examine just 4 rows. So what is there to optimize? And you can get your dates easily with two queries: One to get the date of only the latest entry, and one with LIMIT 9999,1 for the 10,000th row. That's two very quick queries, and no index in the date needed -- you know exactly which rows you want after all!

Comment: I don't understand. Does the result of this query get you the answer you wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to examine the first 10k rows ordered by `id` then you need to use a sub-query to achieve your goal:

```
SELECT MIN(created_at), MAX(created_at)
FROM (
    SELECT created_at
    FROM info
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 10000
) tenK
```

The inner query gets the first 10k rows from the table, sorted by `id` (only the field `created_at` is needed). The outer table computes the minimum and maximum value of `created_at` from the results set generated by the inner query.

I didn't run an `EXPLAIN` on it but I think it says 'Using temporary' in the 'Extra' column (which is not good but you cannot do better for this request). However, 10,000 rows is not that much; it runs fast and the performance does not degrade as the table size increases.

#### Update:

Now I noticed this sentence in the question:

> With this query I want to get the timespan between tha last 10k results.

If you want to get the value of `created_at` of the most recent row and the row that is 10k rows in the past then you can use two simple queries that use the index on `created_at` and run fast:

```
(
    SELECT created_at
    FROM info
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT created_at
    FROM info
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 9999,1
)
ORDER BY created_at
```

This query produces 2 rows, the first one is the value of `created_at` of the 10000th row in the past, the second one is the `created_at` of the most recent row (I assume `created_at` always grows).

Comment: That is inefficient. He already knows he wants only two rows and which ones those are. He can use LIMIT 1 and LIMIT 9999,1 to get the 1st and 10,000th row, respectively, after ordering. No need to get all 10,000 and then on top laboriously max and min over the dates -- which are _ordered_ alongside the id. If you assume or want to protect against a(n unlikely) disconnect between the ordering of those two then you should order by date right away to begin with.

Comment: `9999,1` actually, row numbers start with 0 :-)

Comment: @MörreNoseshine indeed, it is not what the OP asked for. I focused on the query first then I noticed the request was about the 1st and the 10000th row specifically (and not min/max of the first 10k).

Comment: But given the nature of the data that IS the min/max within the selected 10,000 rows, since the dates are ordered alongside with the IDs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT min(created_at), max(created_at) from info order by id DESC limit 10000
```

The above query will give you one row containing the minimum and maximum `created_at` values from `info` table. Because it only returns 1 row, the order by and limit clauses don't come into play.

The 10000-th record from the end can be accessed with the `order by & limit` condition `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 9999` (thanks @Mörre Noseshine for the correction)

So, we can write the intended query as follows:

```
SELECT 
min_created_at.value, 
max_created_at.value
FROM 
(SELECT 
    created_at value 
 FROM info 
 ORDER BY id DESC 
 LIMIT 1 OFFSET 9999) min_created_at,

(SELECT 
    created_at value 
 FROM info 
 ORDER BY id DESC 
 LIMIT 1) max_created_at
```

Comment: (He said 10k, just an aside) I think row numbering starts with 0, so it should be 999 (your example) instead of 1000, I think? See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html -- and you can just [`UNION` the two `SELECT`s...](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

Comment: now I have to go fix this silly error in my codebase